# Toggle display of two divs on click of a link

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two divs in my HTML one will show embedded video from youtube and other will show contact-us input form. There is also a link "Contact Us" above the video.

Initially when page is loaded video is displayed but when user clicks on the "Contact Us" link the video should get hidden and contact-us input form should be displayed in its place.

I'd like to do this using jQuery.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please help us to help you, and try things out yourself first. We can help you figure it out when you get stuck. If you have already tried it out, post some code and tell us your process and any errors that occurred, and what you have done to try and solve them.

Comment: Guide: [What gave you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's `toggle()` or any of the other methods to show and hide your `<div>`s.

Here's a simple example (http://jsfiddle.net/8wbXV/):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="video">
        <a href="#">Contact us</a><br />
        Video here
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
        <a href="#">Return to video</a><br />
        Contact form here
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        $('.container > div').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

This is just a simple example. The selector on the link `$('a')` is not what you'd normally use, but I use it here just for illustration.

Have a look at the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) for more details.